# Make ItemTouchHelper run OnMove only when I release my touch on a RecyclerView List

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I have a basic `RecyclerView` list and added a `ItemTouchHelper` in order to drag and drop list items.

The problem I have with it is that it runs `onMove` on every single list item it passes and it's lagging the app real hard.

Is there a way to implement it so that `onMove` only runs when I release my hold on a `RecyclerView` list item?

Thanks.

MainActivity.java

```
public class pillar_sort extends AppCompatActivity {

private MyRecyclerViewAdapter adapter;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    // Initialize layout
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.pillar_sort);

    final SharedPreferences sharedPref = // Get SharedPreferences
    final ArrayList<String> modules = // Import a list
    final ArrayList<Boolean> visibility = // Import a list
    RecyclerView recyclerView = findViewById(R.id.recyclerView);
    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));
    adapter = new MyRecyclerViewAdapter(this, modules, visibility, cardcolor, txtcolor);
    recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);

    VerticalSpaceItemDecoration decor = new VerticalSpaceItemDecoration();
    recyclerView.addItemDecoration(decor);

    ItemTouchHelper helper = new ItemTouchHelper(new ItemTouchHelper.SimpleCallback(ItemTouchHelper.UP|ItemTouchHelper.DOWN, 0) {
        @Override
        public boolean onMove(@NonNull RecyclerView recyclerView, @NonNull RecyclerView.ViewHolder dragged, @NonNull RecyclerView.ViewHolder target) {
            int position_dragged = dragged.getAdapterPosition();
            int position_target = target.getAdapterPosition();
            Collections.swap(modules,position_dragged,position_target);
            adapter.notifyItemMoved(position_dragged,position_target);
            adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            return false;
        }

        @Override
        public void onSwiped(@NonNull RecyclerView.ViewHolder viewHolder, int direction) {

        }
    });

    helper.attachToRecyclerView(recyclerView);
}
```

MyRecyclerViewAdapter.java

```
public class MyRecyclerViewAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<MyRecyclerViewAdapter.ViewHolder> {

// Variables go here

MyRecyclerViewAdapter( /* a lot of data to pass onto the adapter */ ) {
    // get data from MainActivity and put on variables
}

@Override
public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    View view = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.recyclerview_row, parent, false);
    CardView card = view.findViewById(R.id.card);
    return new ViewHolder(view);
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(final ViewHolder holder, final int position){
    // Put data to TextViews and set card color
}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return modules.size();
}

public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder implements View.OnClickListener {
    TextView myTextView;
    ImageButton image_visibility;

    ViewHolder(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        myTextView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.rowText);
        image_visibility = itemView.findViewById(R.id.imageButton);
        itemView.setOnClickListener(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {

    }
}
```

Comment: can you provide us with your code example?

Comment: @ConfusedPup added some relevant code, I removed some of it because it was irrelevant to the question.